# Replacing WHERE clause with OR by using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

**I have the following query:** that is trying to get pt_ids that have certain diagnosis codes OR certain outcome_codes. I have accounted for these conditions by including the specific codes I'd like in the WHERE clause. However, I would like to know if I can also do this using in INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       pt_id
FROM #df
WHERE flag <> 1
      AND (diagnosis IN
          (
              SELECT Code
              FROM #df_codes
              WHERE code_id = '20'
          )
      OR outcome_code IN
         (
             SELECT Code
             FROM #df_codes
             WHERE code_id = '25'
         ));
```

The above code is taking quite a while to run and I am wondering if writing it in the following way 1) is appropriate/viable and 2) will leader to a faster run time. I am essentially trying to join #df with #df_codes on either Code = diagnosis OR code = outcome_code

**My Solution**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       pt_id
FROM #df a
JOIN (select * from #df_codes where code_id = '20')b ON a.diagnosis = b.Code OR 
(select * from #df_codes where code_id = '25')c ON a.outcome_code = c.Code
WHERE flag <> 1
```

Comment: `OR` conditions are notorious for having performance issues. Convert to 2 queries and `UNUON ALL`.

Comment: You might try an `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, that could have a big impact, though I don't know how many rows of data are in this temp table.

Comment: Temp tables are slow for large data. Remember each Temp table involve IO plus these are not indexed as the original tables. I would suggest to use them only for small data set. How much data are you dealing here?

Comment: @vendettamit, I am working with about 1 million+ rows of data in #df and only about 100-150 rows in df_code

Comment: Do you have (separate) indexes on the `diagnosis` and `outcome_code` for your `#df` table? You should. A million+ rows is a lot for a temp table, especially without indexes.  Including `flag` and `pt_id` as additional indexed or included columns for those two indexes would be an additional improvement. If those indexes are in place, Dale K's suggestion of 2 queries with a UNION (ALL?) would be your best approach. Since the query is looking to return distinct IDs, I think dropping the `DISTINCT` and using a plain `UNION` (no `ALL`) to handle the deduping would achieve the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt_id
FROM #df
INNER JOIN #df_codes ON (
        #df.diagnosis = #df_codes.code
        AND #df_codes.code_id = '20'
        )
    OR (
        #df.outcome_code = #df_codes.code
        AND #df_codes.code_id = '25'
        )
WHERE flag <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough suggestion to create small temp tables and join it back to main table. I would suggest use the CTE or original table query and do following:

```
SELECT Code
into #x
FROM #df_codes
WHERE code_id = '20'

SELECT Code
into #y
FROM #df_codes
WHERE code_id = '25'


SELECT
pt_id
FROM #df
join #x x on x.Code = diagnosis 
WHERE flag <> 1
Union
SELECT
pt_id
FROM #df
join #y y on y.Code = diagnosis 
WHERE flag <> 1
```

Just replace #df by a CTE that way you can use the existing indexes.

Comment: #y should join on outcome_code instead of diagnosis in the above answer.

Comment: `UNION ALL` **not** `UNION` for performance reasons

Answer (score -1):

Use EXISTS instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       d.pt_id
  FROM #df  d
 WHERE flag <> 1
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM #df_codes c
                WHERE (c.code = d.diagnosis AND c.code_id = '20')
                   OR (c.code = d.outcome_code AND c.code_id = '25');
```

If #df lists each patient a single time - then you don't need the DISTINCT.  If you try using a join and a patient has both then you would get 2 rows - and then use DISTINCT to eliminate the 'duplicates'.